# Why the transaction is not locked

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I don't understand why the second transaction is not blocked as the first one is not rollbacked or commited.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE [Direction]
SET [Name] = N'Example1'
WHERE [DirectionID] = 1;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE [Direction]
SET [Name] = N'Example2'
WHERE [DirectionID] = 1;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have nested transactions. Are you trying to do this in two separate windows?

Comment: Nope, there is only one file is named `file1.sql` :)

Comment: The second `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` doesn't do anything. The point of enclosing your session's activity inside a transaction is to block _another session_ from those same rows. Blocking yourself doesn't make much sense - what does the second `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` have to wait for in order to be able to move on? Official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql) might be useful starting points.

Comment: Actually, the second `BEGIN TRANSACTION` does do something; it increments the transaction count. Two `COMMIT` statements are required at the end of the script to commit the work. Otherwise, a transaction will be left open and rolled back when the session is closed. Of course, the inner transaction serves no purpose here and should be removed.

Comment: @Dan What I meant was it doesn't effectively do anything to your session and, as you said, serves no purpose here. The increment of `@@TRANCOUNT` is largely performative and leads people to believe transactions are nested or the count really matters, or there is some reason to call `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` multiple times, which [leads to different behavior in the case of rollback](https://dbfiddle.uk/SxuWe936).